# _popen fails to return java version

Tags: c++, windows, popen

In my C++ on Windows program I have to collect java version by firing the command "java -version".

I am using _popen API for the same.

When I use _popen command for firing any windows command prompt commands then _open returns properly the output of the command in the buffer.

```
char versionCmd[256] = "";
char buffer[1024];

strcpy(versionCmd, "netstat -an");
FILE *File_p = _popen(versionCmd, "r");
if (!File_p)
{
    return -1;
}

while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), File_p))
{
    printf("buffer = %s", buffer);
}
```

But when I run the same program with command "java -version" then _popen does not return anything in the buffer.

```
strcpy(versionCmd, "java -version");
```

Instead the output gets printed on the console from where I ran this windows program.

Looks like the output of the command is getting redirected to console instead of buffer.

Is there anyway I can redirect the output of the "java -version" command to the program's buffer?
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could Java be writing to stderr ?   From the cmd prompt try `java -version 1>out1.txt 2>out2.txt`  out1.txt will be the contents of stdout and out2.txt will be stderr

Comment: Thanks Richard for the reply.
From the command you suggested java -version is getting collected in out2.txt.
So the java command output is going to stderr.

Is there any way to redirect the stderr to stdout or in the program's buffer on windows?

Comment: Sorry no idea ...

Comment: I redirected the output using "2>&1" and it worked and I am able to get the output in my program's buffer. So new command is "java -version 2>&1".

Your words "Could Java be writing to stderr" redirected me properly to the problematic area.